# How to enlarge Gimp UI font and icon size for HDPI screen?

Tags: macos, gimp, user-interface, dpi

I'm using Gimp for Mac on a 4k screen and the interface text and icons look tiny. How can I make it bigger?

Answer (score 22):

**Change icon size**

- Preferences

  - Interface

    - Icon Theme

      - Change: *guess Icon size from resolution*
      - Into: *custom Icon Size*
      - Drag slider

**Change font size**

- *Close Gimp*
- Open the file `gtkrc` of your specific theme in a text editor

  - Open the Gimp themes directory:

    - Mac: `/Applications/GIMP-2.10.app/Contents/Resources/share/gimp/2.0/themes/`
    - Windows: `C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\share\gimp\2.0\themes\`
    - Ubuntu: `/usr/share/gimp/2.0/themes/`
  - Open the gtkrc file for your theme:

    - Light: `Light/gtkrc`
    - Dark: `Dark/gtkrc`
    - Gray: `Gray/gtkrc`
    - System `System/gtkrc`
    - **other**
      *If you have a customized Gimp, look here for the gtkrc file*

      - Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/GIMP/2.10/themes`
- Find line with: `GimpDock::font-scale = 0.8333`
- Replace with: `GimpDock::font-scale = 1.6666` (or another value)
- *Start Gimp again*

Comment: Custom Icon size behaves strangely: large and huge are smaller than medium size on my DELL xps 15 4k (gimp 2.10.18) https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/issues/2313

Comment: Linux equivalents in Ubuntu are in `/usr/share/gimp/2.0/themes/Dark/gtkrc` and similar for the other themes

Comment: Thank you @LucasW, added!

Comment: This works for almost every UI element, but the main menu bar is still small for me. I suppose that's being controlled by the desktop environment.

Comment: @Pistos see answer explaining to change the font.

Comment: @DavidRios Even though I change that `GimpDock` line in the gtkrc file in my theme, it still shows the menu bar as pretty small.

Comment: @small_improvement 's answer helped me, though. https://superuser.com/a/1722799/8997

Comment: "Change: guess Icon size from resolution Into: custom Icon Size; Drag slider" This only provides Small and Medium. Large and Huge are disabled. Presumably not available in the themes.

Comment: @Pistos I meant the answer below this one. Instead of changing the GimpDock line, change the font_name. https://superuser.com/a/1722799/386047

Answer (score 9):

Under [Bodhi Linux](https://www.bodhilinux.com/) a better solution for me is similar to Bouke Versteegh's except leave.

`GimpDock::font-scale = 0.8333`

alone.  Instead, uncomment

`# font_name = "sans 10"`

and change it to

`font_name = "sans 20"`.

If you examine the `gtkrc` file, you will see there are several places where various font scales are specified.  Changing the font changes them all without fussing with specific scales.  If you want to tweak it afterwards, then you can alter specific scaling settings to change relative sizes for various parts of the interface.

Note: I had previously altered the bootup system environment variables with

`GDK_SCALE=2`

which GIMP apparently does not honor.  My menu bar remained unreadable when I only adjusted the scale in `gtkrc`.

Comment: This is the correct answer on Windows. - Setting font_name to sans 16 is perfect on a 4k 43" desktop monitor. I guess a value of 20 or above would be more usable on 4k notebook displays. Gimp should really use a sensible default here based on system hidpi settings and not just fall back to the values which worked on 640x480 displays...

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10/11, you have to edit the **gtkrc** file (This can be found [in the case of Dark theme] in C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\share\gimp\2.0\themes\Dark) of the theme you are using. Then you have to select that theme in GIMP's *Preferences* (Menu Bar >> Edit >> Preferences).

Changing the font-scale value wont increase the font size in the menus. You have to change the font size in two places and you have to uncomment the lines.

This part of the code has to be edited (It is found in the beginning):

```
#gtk-font-name = "Sans 11"

# KDE hack to match gtk/gnome defaults gtk-button-images = 0 style "gimp-dark-default-style"

{  #font_name = "Sans 11"
```

This is the edited version:

```
gtk-font-name = "Sans 20"

# KDE hack to match gtk/gnome defaults gtk-button-images = 0 style "gimp-dark-default-style"

{  font_name = "Sans 20"
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that worked for me to also change the menus text is:

Edit the file (in my case **C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\share\gimp\2.0\themes\Dark\gtkrc**)

Under the theme that you have chosen (could be Dark/Light/Grey/etc) in my case

```
style "gimp-dark-default-style" {
```

uncomment the line

```
  font_name = "Sans 11"
```

and add below

```
  GtkLabel::use-underline = TRUE
```

so it looks something like:

```
.
.
.
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme = true

# gtk-font-name = "Sans 11"

# KDE hack to match gtk/gnome defaults
gtk-button-images = 0

style "gimp-dark-default-style"
{
  font_name = "Sans 11"
  GtkLabel::use-underline = TRUE

  color["clr1"]  = "#DDDDDD"
  color["clr2"]  = "#FFFFFF"
.
.
.
```