# Gimp UI scaling on Windows: gtkrc menu background colour and icon sizes?

Tags: gimp, gtk, gtk-windows

Gimp's default scaling on Windows sucks, so I have to manually scale it. I saw an existing [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1513000/how-to-enlarge-gimp-ui-font-and-icon-size-for-hdpi-screen), and tried to modify the "gtkrc" file of the dark theme. However, I could not find the values for the menu background colour, or the icon sizes. Could someone tell me which values I should edit for the following things?

1. menu background colour
2. menu icon size
3. tab size
4. panel icon size
5. file close button icon size

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The menu background is an image: ui/menu.png

I'll have experiment to see if it's possible to change the icons sizes, but it might mean you'll have to create the complete set in larger sizes.

Back in the day of GIMP 2.8 I made some larger versions of the symbolic icon set but with 2.10 having a preferences-selectable icon theme size, it might not work now. https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-GIMP-2-8-Large-size-Icons-Themes

Comment: I think it is very dumb to show icons only in their original pixel size. No wonder why Gimp's UI scaling sucked. Fixed pixel sizes for images means no scaling for icons according to the screen DPI! I think I will double (width*2, height*2) all images with a simple C# code and see how that looks.

Comment: I've now found how to do this and make use of the scalable icons: https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-How-to-change-the-menu-icon-size?pid=20406#pid20406